# Alfresco Java backend webscript: reading properties file

Tags: alfresco, resourcebundle

I need to include a properties file into my Alfresco webscript developed in Java.
How can I include it?
The properties file includes a hash map useful for service work.

How can use ResourceBundle?

Note that it is not a i18n file.

Thanks

-- Marco

Comment: Is this a `foo.get.properties` file for a matching `foo.get.desc.xml` webscript, or a different sort of properties file?

Comment: did the answer solve ya problem?

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to get your props as map via spring injection with your java webscript bean:

```
    <property name="your map">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="location" value="your_properties.properties"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Comment: Agree you can include it this way in your webscript.